# How do i get value from two inputs in INSERT?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert

How do a get the value of `select name= 'type'` included with the `INSERT` of `'description'`???

```
Array ( 
  [0] => 23000 
  [1] => 1452 
  [2] => Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`dblabb`.`items`, CONSTRAINT `fk_items_itemtypes_id` FOREIGN KEY (`type`) REFERENCES `itemtypes` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE) 
)
  if(isset($_POST['addItem'])){
  $query = "INSERT INTO items(type,description)  VALUES (':type:id', ':desc')";
  $name = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'desc',FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);

  $sth = $db->prepare($query);
     if($sth->execute(array(':desc' =>$name)``)){

        echo "<h4>Item added</h4>";

      }else{
        echo "<h4>Error</h4>";
        echo "<pre>" . print_r($sth->errorInfo()) . "</pre>";
   }

   <form action="dblabb3.php" method="post">
   <select name="type">
        <?php

        $query = "SELECT * FROM itemtypes ORDER BY name ASC";
        if ($result = $db->query($query)) {
              while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {
                    echo '<option value="' . $row['0'] . '">' .
                            $row['1'] . '</option>';
              }
        } ?>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="desc" placeholder="description">
    <input type="submit" name="addItem" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your execute statement has only one element in the array [desc] but type is required as well.

Should rather look like:

```
if($sth->execute(array(':type:id'=>$TYPE,':desc' =>$name){}
```

Comment: i get this message in my IDE: Cannot use [] for reading? Heard of that?

Comment: Still the same problem.

Comment: Array ( [0] => 23000 [1] => 1452 [2] => Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`dblabb`.`items`, CONSTRAINT `fk_items_itemtypes_id` FOREIGN KEY (`type`) REFERENCES `itemtypes` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE) )

Comment: Please post your current code. Type is a foreign key so it MUST match the foreign key constraint! I do not know how your database looks like. But it would clear the matter if you output the sql for the tables in question.

Comment: Just one example to clarify the foreign key:

table car (id int 10 autoincrement,manufacturer char(25),color int 10 foreign key colors.id)

table colors(id int 10, color char(20))

if colors is
id........color
01 .......red
02 .......black
and you insert a new car by

insert into car(manufacturer,color)values('PORSCHE',6)
it will fail with the message that you are getting, because color #6 doesn't exist.

Hope that helps